# Listview item click open another listview with different data for each item click

Tags: listview, android-listview, listviewitem

I am new in Android development. I want to make an app. Here have a listview with some item like classOne, classTwo, classThree, classFour, classFive. Every class has different student list. When I click an item in first listview, then open another listview with different student list for each item. How can I do it, please help me. I will be pleased to you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i already creat first listview.